# Mathematics is Material

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The instructions for this puzzle...darn it, I wrote them down around here somewhere. Well, you're smart so I'm sure you'll figure it out!

[image]

CSV:

```
O,H,T,N,E,Z,R,I,G,M,R,V,P,O,U,E,N,L,I,O,I,E,D,F,I,E,S
N,Y,F,P,O,P,O,U,N,D,S,E,N,H,E,R,O,I,C,U,N,I,L,A,J,D,T
I,Z,A,R,U,S,W,N,B,N,H,A,C,D,W,P,A,D,E,S,R,D,C,Y,O,M,N
M,T,O,I,T,E,S,T,G,R,I,G,R,A,T,D,A,E,R,B,L,E,S,I,D,R,F
O,F,F,E,R,P,C,I,R,F,N,E,I,N,S,A,D,Q,U,S,G,K,I,D,O,I,B
I,G,R,E,L,E,S,L,R,E,E,M,T,I,O,W,R,A,U,N,K,N,T,H,Y,E,U
A,G,D,E,A,A,K,N,E,I,T,R,U,S,B,Y,O,S,I,O,I,X,R,H,I,N,S
E,X,A,C,T,L,Y,E,L,A,E,F,A,N,R,R,W,R,N,O,S,H,R,U,G,D,N
B,T,A,I,A,C,I,A,T,E,N,U,L,I,A,E,R,S,A,P,D,H,O,R,E,I,C
N,I,P,E,V,P,L,D,S,T,H,E,I,N,S,T,R,U,W,B,O,U,A,N,E,E,H
U,S,U,R,F,U,P,O,I,C,T,I,O,N,S,F,O,R,G,U,O,F,R,I,A,L,N
D,S,A,I,G,T,E,L,S,T,H,I,S,P,U,Z,Z,L,T,E,I,H,F,O,A,S,E
T,T,H,R,E,E,F,A,E,E,A,R,E,W,R,I,T,T,R,K,E,T,I,M,S,S,P
L,E,L,E,S,A,N,T,H,E,N,O,N,A,P,A,R,C,I,T,E,N,D,T,I,E,R
B,R,S,H,E,R,O,I,N,H,M,E,N,T,U,N,D,E,P,P,H,E,W,I,T,S,I
R,E,W,O,L,F,C,H,A,R,M,R,S,I,E,R,P,I,Q,U,E,I,Y,H,U,P,E
O,R,U,S,S,E,E,L,D,N,S,K,I,S,T,A,T,T,C,O,L,I,N,Y,O,G,A
T,D,A,T,M,R,U,I,U,E,R,Y,C,A,R,P,E,T,N,L,W,F,R,K,N,E,D
R,P,T,E,P,R,T,A,N,T,U,R,M,L,I,V,C,N,U,A,T,B,D,F,A,A,L
T,O,L,K,R,O,O,M,Y,C,O,R,K,R,O,I,E,S,O,F,N,E,O,P,L,R,I
S,O,E,D,H,T,W,O,L,K,H,T,L,R,B,Y,E,N,L,A,X,R,M,R,T,A,E
H,Q,I,L,L,B,I,M,E,O,O,M,E,A,W,N,N,A,E,R,L,O,R,D,R,R,T
T,M,D,F,I,N,R,I,S,I,N,G,D,I,N,I,G,E,R,C,A,T,H,E,U,O,T
U,O,F,C,E,L,J,S,E,N,R,N,L,S,L,A,E,F,B,E,R,E,F,T,U,A,W
D,O,D,M,R,E,O,T,E,S,I,P,E,S,N,M,A,A,Y,W,M,E,A,R,T,H,E
P,N,E,R,N,R,N,E,I,N,C,O,S,T,S,L,W,D,E,A,L,F,L,A,I,L,S
P,R,S,A,C,D,A,R,L,W,N,E,S,E,T,M,E,F,E,D,O,S,P,E,B,R,H
```

Solver Notes: Definition of a word in this puzzle:

1. appears in /usr/share/dict/words:https://gist.github.com/WChargin/8927565
2. appears contiguously in the grid in a single direction
3. does not appear within another legitimate word

Comment: There's no minimum letter count restriction for what counts as a 'word'?

Comment: That remains to be seen :-)

Comment: @deu rule 3 rules out many.

Comment: the first word I saw was "Carpet"... hmm

Comment: @matt: I would say that technically the first word you saw is "Car", but that would violate the definition of word in this puzzle.

Comment: How much time it took to order the Alphabets here or is it just a copy/paste?

Comment: @MdBasha I don't think I understand the question.

Comment: Just wondering how much time you have spent for this alphabet arrangement :)

Comment: @MdBasha It wasn't too hard. Biggest challenge was ensuring no stray words crept in, but used a computer program to check. Actual time spent was probably 4-5 hours.

Comment: A computer program for check? Cool. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First:

> The middle 9x9 region of the grid spells out a message. "THE INSTRUCTIONS FOR THIS PUZZLE ARE WRITTEN UNDER SIERPINSKI'S TATTERY CARPET".
>
>  Sierpinski's carpet is a mathematical fractal. We can apply three iterations of Sierpinski's carpet to the puzzle...
>
>  [image]
>  and this gives two new messages! One is in the deleted 3×3 blocks, and the other is in the deleted single cells.
>  `ITERATE SIERPINSKI DELETION THREE TIMES AND THERE WILL BE A WORD FIND IN THE CELLS LEFT`
>  `YOU SHOULD FIND SIXTEEN WORDS FOUR LETTERS LONG OR MORE FORMING A CONNECT WALL`.

So, follow the instructions!

> Deleting all the letters in the instructions gives a word search with 16 words hidden in it:
>  [image]
>  The words are: APPLE, BREAD, BROAD, CLEAN, CROSS, EARTH, FLAT, FLOWER, HIGH, HOLE, INCH, MAIN, RING, ROWS, TAPE, TRIP.
>
>  Now we have to solve the Connect Wall. On the show, the categories can be anything, but it seems here the categories are all words that come before or after the sets.
>
>  BREAD, FLOWER, ROWS, HOLE can all come after CORN.
>  EARTH, RING, INCH, TAPE can all come before WORM.
>  APPLE, CROSS, HIGH, TRIP all make a phrase with ROAD.
>  BROAD, CLEAN, FLAT, MAIN all make a phrase with SHEET.
>
>  Additionally, all four of these connecting words have a connection in themselves: they make a phrase with SILK, which fits the "carpet" theme.

(Thanks to El-Guest and hexomino for helping me fill in some of the final bits.)

Comment: Awesome. You got almost all of it. You should be confident of the stuff you're confident in, and not as confident in the stuff you're not as confident in...though the latter is not far off. I can say your current groupings are not correct.

Comment: @JeremyDover Hm, *all* the groupings are wrong? Interesting.

Comment: Oops...I did not mean that. The one that you think might not be right is not right.

Comment: @JeremyDover Ah, that makes more sense. I'll think about it some more. (I also noticed a ROAD grouping, but it seems like before/after might be inconsistent there.)

Comment: I would not discount that...

Comment: Perhaps rot13(FGERRG) as a third grouping would include rot13(ZNVA) instead of rot13(SYNG)?

Comment: Actually it is safe to assume that I was never consistent about before/after. Was not sure that was a constraint on the puzzle type...assumed "phrase containing _" would be sufficient category for a connection, but please educate me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JeremyDover Usually, the phrases are consistent about that, but I don't think they necessarily *have* to be.

Comment: @El-Guest Maybe? ROAD looks possible too - it would also give ROAD TRIP as an option. I also found TRIP LINE, BROADLINE, FLATLINE, but the first two are a bit obscure. Still having trouble with APPLE and CLEAN though.

Comment: I'm wondering if the final connection is rot13(UBYR - jbezubyr, pbeaubyr (tnzr), ebnq ubyr (tbys) naq bar bgure V fgvyy pna'g frr...) Would be appropriate what with the carpet theme...

Comment: @Stiv That's one of the words. (But yes, I did consider it for WORM too, and it *does* seem thematic...)

Comment: Ha, d'oh - ignore me! I should clearly get some sleep...

Comment: @Deusovi — how about [this little gem](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/road+apple)

Comment: I live in a rural area. @El-Guest is a wise person.

Comment: @JeremyDover Oh, interesting - I'd never heard that one before! With that I *think* I have all the connections, but I'm still not sure about the last one...

Comment: @Deusovi A flat sheet is a thing (essentially it's a bed sheet which is not a "fitted sheet")

Comment: That's it! @hexomino has the last connection correct. Hope you enjoyed!